# Can we run scenarios in sequence using @tag in spring boot cucumber test application. Language used is java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, appium

I have one spring boot cucumber based test automation and I want to run scenarios in a specific sequence. Below is my feature file example:

**Login.feature**

```
@Login
Scenario: check login
Given user is on login page
When user enter id and password
Then user should be logged in
```

**Admin.feature**

```
@admin
Scenario: check admin panel
Given user is logged in
Then user should see admin panel buttons
```

By default, it runs in alphabetical order. I want to run in a specific sequence either from cli or using @tag

Comment: Simply I would update the Scenario description something like `Scenario: Step-1:check login` and `Scenario: Step-2:check admin panel` to handle this.

Comment: thanks supputuri but I have multiple feature files containing multiple features and I want ro run scenarios in specific sequence. In earlier version I used to run it using @tags=['@login','@admin','@xyz'] which is not supported in new version.